# Database Meta tools

Tags: sql, relational-database, database-design, database-metadata

I'm now working with a legacy database which is missing, among almost everything you'd expect from a decent SQL relational DB, any documentation or metadata. I can't make changes to the DB schema, except my local test copy, as it exists at many client sites and there's no upgrading procedures. Are there any tools that I can use to build and keep my own meta about the database? I'm looking to keep track of relationships, basic documentation about tables and columns, and references in stored procedures. There's 200+ tables and 3300+ SPs. A base autogeneration would be very helpful, particularly with the SPs. Preferably FOSS and Linux, but I will settle for win just to have something.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "metadata", but I'm pretty happy with Liquibase.

It manages the schema in one (or more) XML files and can reverse engineer an existing database (all major ones supported).

It's Java/JDBC based and runs fine on Linux

The main purposes of Liquibase is to handle upgrades (schema migration) smoothly, so I'm not sure if this exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: There's no descriptions on tables or columns. Lots of relationships are missing. Stored procedures aren't self descriptive or have notes, etc.